# How to put table into multicols

Tags: tables, multicol, description, tabbing

I'm trying to get table formated like this:

```
A    desription of A      D    description of D
B    long description     Eee  description of Eee
     of B                 F    description of F
Cccc description of Cccc
```

and I'm limited with space on the page where this table should be.

When I use `\begin{tabular}{lp{5cm}lp{5cm}}` I get table which is too long to fit onto the page, `longtable` with same parameters throws last line onto next page.

With `multicols` package I tried `tabbing` environment, but *long description of B* goes over *Eee* and `longtable` throws error that it can
t be used in twocolumn. `description` environment can do that sort of things but I can't force it to align *descriptions*

Is there chance to make this table automatically without experimenting with `\\`positioning or creating two independent tables?

Comment: You can use the package ltxtable with the column X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `description` environment, it works in twocolumn mode as well and matches the original meaning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn
\begin{description}
  \item[A] description of A
  \item[B] long description of B
  ...
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

There are packages such as [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) and [`mdwlist`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdwlist) which provide tools for customizing the layout of the `description` list, so you don't have to use the default layout but can make it look like a table.

Comment: Thanks for fast and accurate answer. I've added the code I used. It works exactly as I want.

Comment: @Crowley there's no need to put the solution back into the question.  Stefan's answer, and your having accepted it will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

You may try `tabularx` from the **tabularx** package

```
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}lXlX@{}}
```

I've used `@{}` at left and right to give the table maximum room.

Comment: The first suggestion is fitting tabular ultimately into width of paper but it doesn't spare the blank space forced by *long description of D*. And `tabularx` inside 'multicols' doesn't break into the second column - it overflows off the page.

Comment: @Crowley: my first suggestion was actually wrong. Wide tables in two column format should be avoided, as they are likely to give problems. A `tabularx` is like `tabular` and can't be broken.